# Assign Case Statement to variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to assign `case` statement result to variable but I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

My code:

```
DECLARE @Test    VARCHAR(10)='Yes';DECLARE @strTest VARCHAR(max);SELECT 
@strTest = 
   CASE 
          WHEN @Test = 'YES' THEN '{ status:"' + Isnull(column1,'') + '", 
                       dateLabel:'''+ 
                 CASE 
                     WHEN column1='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column1_dt 
                        AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                        ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                 END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + '},' + '{ 
                     status:"' + Isnull(column2,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                 CASE 
                        WHEN column2='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column2_dt 
                     AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                        ELSE Isnull(column2_owner,'') 
                 END + ''', title: '+ '''Update Column2''' + '},' + 
                 CASE 
                        WHEN @Test = 'No' 
                        OR     @Test IS NULL THEN '{ status:"' + 
                        Isnull(column1,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                               CASE 
                                      WHEN column1='complete' THEN 
                                Isnull(Cast(column1_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                                      ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                               END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + 
                              '},' 
                        ELSE '' 
                 END 
          from   [Project] 
          WHERE  project_id = @Project_Id
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue? I am stuck with this query.

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the SQL Server version?

Comment: `CASE` - 5 occurences, `END` - 4 occurences => One of the CASE expression is not properly enclosed. Anyway SQL Server 2016+ supports `FOR JSON`

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. And it's times l;ike this that a little bit of ***good*** formatting will likely tell yo the problem immediately.

Comment: @marc_s: I had to rollback your edit, because it invalidates my answer - sorry about that. I thought about deleting my answer instead, but I think it may be useful for others to know about pretty printers as a generic debugging technique for this kind of problem.

Comment: If you are trying to build a JSON output and if you are using SQL Server 2016+, you may use `FOR JSON` and simplify your statement.

Answer (score 2):

Running your SQL through a pretty printer (e.g. [this one](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)):

```
DECLARE @Test    VARCHAR(10)='Yes';DECLARE @strTest VARCHAR(max);SELECT @strTest = 
       CASE 
              WHEN @Test = 'YES' THEN '{ status:"' + Isnull(column1,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+ 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN column1='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column1_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                            ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                     END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + '},' + '{ status:"' + Isnull(column2,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                     CASE 
                            WHEN column2='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column2_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                            ELSE Isnull(column2_owner,'') 
                     END + ''', title: '+ '''Update Column2''' + '},' + 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN @Test = 'No' 
                            OR     @Test IS NULL THEN '{ status:"' + Isnull(column1,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                                   CASE 
                                          WHEN column1='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column1_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                                          ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                                   END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + '},' 
                            ELSE '' 
                     END 
              from   [Project] 
              WHERE  project_id = @Project_Id
```

reveals that you did not close your outmost `CASE` statement.

I *guess* that this is what you wanted to write (removing `+ CASE` somewhere in the middle):

```
DECLARE @Test    VARCHAR(10)='Yes';
DECLARE @strTest VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @strTest = 
       CASE 
              WHEN @Test = 'YES' THEN '{ status:"' + Isnull(column1,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+ 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN column1='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column1_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                            ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                     END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + '},' + '{ status:"' + Isnull(column2,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                     CASE 
                            WHEN column2='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column2_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                            ELSE Isnull(column2_owner,'') 
                     END + ''', title: '+ '''Update Column2''' + '},'

              WHEN @Test = 'No' OR @Test IS NULL THEN '{ status:"' + Isnull(column1,'') + '", dateLabel:'''+
                     CASE 
                            WHEN column1='complete' THEN Isnull(Cast(column1_dt AS VARCHAR(30)),'')
                            ELSE Isnull(column1_owner,'') 
                     END + ''', title: '+ '''Initiate Column1 ''' + '},' 

              ELSE '' 
       END
from   [Project] 
WHERE  project_id = @Project_Id
```

Comment: I guess it is same query as above i run your query in SQL and still i am getting same error

Comment: @Bhushan: Yep, because I only showed you the problem, not the solution (because we cannot know the solution). I have added an educated guess to my answer.